# How oozie executes the prepare steps?

Tags: oozie

Is oozie execute all the prepare steps (like delete) once at the beginning of the workflow?

Is it run all prepare step even if the given action never "called"?

I experience that it deleted some of my data folder but I never called the action where the prepare step was specified. And it seems it's deleted right after the first action called (which had no prepare step).

Answer (score 0):

The `prepare` commands are executed at the start of the each action. They are not executed at once in the start of the workflow or anything like that. These commands are issued by the oozie server.